# update query to last inserted raw id in sq-lite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table in which i m inserting datas except one field at a time, another time i want to insert the non filled data, i m trying to update the table with this value. i tried the below query but getting error. plz help me how to do it

```
  public boolean insertConfigStartTime(Long StartTime)
{
    ContentValues updateContentValues = ConfigStartTimeValue(StartTime);

    if(this.data.update("tb_Config", updateContentValues, "id=select last_insert_rowid()", null)>0)
    return true;
    else
    return false;

}


    public ContentValues ConfigStartTimeValue(Long StartTime)
{
    ContentValues configContentvalues = new ContentValues();
    configContentvalues.put("ProcessStartTime", StartTime);
    return configContentvalues;

}
```

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: 05-16 09:45:24.133: E/AndroidRuntime(7073): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-16 09:45:24.133: E/AndroidRuntime(7073): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "select": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE tb_Config SET ProcessStartTime=? WHERE id=select last_insert_rowid()

Comment: Your query is not correct.

Comment: @ZouZou could you help me to correct it

Comment: WHat is select last_insert_rowid() ? Is it a method in your code ?

Comment: i got this by searching on google for getting the last inserted row id from the table. i have doubt on this

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
"id = last_insert_rowid()"
```

However, this works only if you are using the same database object for the insert and the update, i.e., the database connection must not haven been closed/reopened.